# Visibility of user control section

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a user control containing a panel at its lower edge. This panel contains some controls.
Now I want to make this panel invisible at runtime, but instead of showing the user controls background (where the panel was), I would like to show a portion of the form here.
How can I do that?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. Please clarify your problem, add code demonstrating what you've tried so far and compare the actual and expected results.

Comment: What UI framework are you using? WPF, Winforms, Webforms?

Comment: I Try This In Windows Forms

Comment: I Have An User Control , That I put a Panel On It.

Comment: When I put This User Control On A Windows Form

Comment: What Can I Do For This Solution ...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please show a screenshot.

Comment: Excuse me John Saunders ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the panel on the `UserControl` is docked at its bottom. When making the panel invisible, decrase the height of the user control by the height of the panel.

```
userControl1.panel1.Visible = false;
userControl1.Height -= userControl1.panel1.Height;
```

If the code is in the form, the `panel1` must be `public` or `internal` for this to work. If the code is in the user control itself, you can simply write:

```
panel1.Visible = false;
Height -= panel1.Height;
```